# How to stop Drop event in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a directive for an input field in Angular2 application. I want to stop Paste or <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> to the host of this directive so I used following code and the code is working perfectly.

```
@HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(e: KeyboardEvent) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

I also want to stop Drop event to that host. How can I do It?

Comment: Please check if mousedrop event is working in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it by guess. It is working.

```
@HostListener('drop', ['$event']) blockDrop(e: MouseEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Comment: There are multiple events in angular4, you have to figure which one do you need to make your case.

Comment: That was my mistake. Actually I need to stop only Drop event.

Answer (score 2):

```
@HostListener('mousedown', ['$event']) blockMouseDown(e: MouseEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

I hope it might help.

Comment: mousedown not only block the drop it also stop the focusing on that host using mouse.